# XCODE doesnt recognize my new storyboard.xib file to create localization file

Tags: ios, xcode

I added another two storyboard.xib files to XCODE

What I want is to create new Localize file,
But my Xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002) recognize only Main.storyboard, and LauchScreen.storyboard.

Something need to set? I check all settings, but couldn't find.

If youu know, would you please give me advice.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose `your storyboard` you want to localize, open `File inspector` -> choose `Localize`.

[image: Click to show image]

You can apply this way for any other xib file that you want to localize.